# How do I make a new header file of my own library visible in a CocoaPods-based project?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I use CocoaPods for developing an app that also uses a private library "MyLib" I develop in parallel to the app. MyLib maintains its own podspec and is referenced in the app's podfile like so:

```
pod 'MyLib', :path => '~/Projects/iOS/Own/Frameworks/mylib'
```

I noticed that CocoaPods maintains its own public header file directory for MyLib at /pods/Headers/Public/MyLib and includes that directory in compiling source files from the app.

My question: what makes CocoaPods update this header files directory if I add a new public category to MyLib.xcodeproj that I want to use in the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pod install or pod update need to be executed whenever your add a new file to your pod doesn't matter if it is public header or private implementation file. Old files can be changed without updating

Comment: pod update indeed did the trick once I added the header file to the library's Copy Files Build Phase. Thanks.